# Detect long press in Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I would like to detect in my game the long press touch, but the problem is `CCTargetedTouchDelegate` in `Cocos2d 3.0` doesn't exist anymore to implement its `delegates`. How can i do that?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, Might be worth avoiding tagging with 3.0 to discourage its use as discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85744/171964)

Comment: I would agree with the 2.x tags but not 3.0 which is just too different from 2.x and earlier. Most of the class names have changed for instance, an answer giving even a short cocos2d 2.x code example will very likely not work with 3.x and vice versa. Besides, this question is clearly asking for advice on how this particular thing works with v3.0, so the tag is valid here even by Jeff's definition. ;)

Comment: @JamesWebster Oh, I see you removed the v3 tag from at least 20+ questions. Could you please undo the tag removals? I'm adding this tag to cocos2d questions specifically because v3 is so different from earlier versions. Same with cocos2d-3.x. Though you can remove the 2.x tags, no loss there.

Comment: Hmm. Well you've certainly got me rethinking, however I've removed *all* of the tags now. Practically all of the questions I edited however, mention the version number in the title and/or the question. Isn't this a good way for it to work? Otherwise we'll end up with a list of ever diluted tags as new versions of software / libraries / etc are released.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>`CCTargetedTouchDelegate` does still exist, but it has been renamed [`CCTouchOneByOneDelegate`](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/2.1.0/protocol_c_c_touch_one_by_one_delegate-p.html).</strike> (This is only valid for 2.1+)

It appears touch control has been moved to a [`CCResponder`](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/3.0-rc1/Classes/CCResponder.html). Instead of delegates, it appears to expect you to subclass it and override the touch methods:

```
– touchBegan:withEvent:
– touchMoved:withEvent:
– touchEnded:withEvent:
– touchCancelled:withEvent:
```

However for a long press, I'd probably still use the [`UILongPressGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/attachments/1782/XTLayer.zip download this file. It has implemented different gestures

```
void xtTapGesture(CCPoint position) {}
virtual void xtDoubleTapGesture(CCPoint position) {}
virtual void xtLongTapGesture(CCPoint position) {}
virtual void xtSwipeGesture(XTTouchDirection direction, float distance, float speed) {}
```

you extend cclayer in your header file .. replace it with XTLayer and replace all touch events with xt instead of cc.

you can get more detail on http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/23011

hope this helps.